# find/xargs, filenames with spaces, and quotes

Tags: find, xargs

I'm looking for a way to get `find` and `xargs` (GNUWin32, under Win7, both programs at version 4.1) to play along, with filenames that contain spaces.

Getting the filenames *into* `xargs` as one was one challenge, but I seem to find no way of getting them *out* in one piece. Unluckily, `xargs` strips off quotes, no matter what I try.
This causes `lame` (which is to be called from `xargs`) to complain about superfluous arguments as the filenames contain spaces.

Yes, I am aware of `find`'s `-exec` option (which would work without `xargs`), I am explicitly not interested in that, since I wish to run 8 parallel instances of `lame` for a somewhat computionally intensive batch task (re-encode roughly 1,800 192kbit/s audiobook mp3s so they'll fit onto my player's micro-sd card). That is, `xargs -P 8`.

This command:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -printf "\"%P\" --abr 52 -q 0 --silent \"conv/%P\" " | xargs -n 7
```

will output something akin to:

```
path/01.01 foo bar.mp3 --abr 52 -q 0 --silent conv/path/path/01.01 foo bar.mp3
```

... which still lacks the quotes, so if I put `lame` at the end of that command, it will consider `path/01.01` as input, `foo` as output, and complain that there is a superfluous `bar.mp3` argument.

- I have tried adding apostrophes (around the quotes, and inside them), but `xargs" strips those out, too.
- `-print0` will not do either (at least for anything I've tried).
- I have tried simulating `-print0` with `printf` and `\0`, to no avail.
- Meanwhile I'm playing with the idea of redirecting the output to a file and adding the quotes with a text editor...

Comment: Ended up redirecting all to a file, splitting the file in 8 pieces, and running the 8 pieces in parallel by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended usage:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

... if you say `-print0` for find, then you need `-0` for xargs.

For what it is worth, I often find xargs a nuisance - in those cases I take care to build the exact commands I want to execute with `find -printf` and then finally append `| bash` to it.

Comment: Aware of that flag, but this won't work either, sadly, still need quotes for `lame`.

Comment: Try `find -printf` with added `\"` quotes and piped into bash as I said above then.

Comment: Well, the point of `xargs` is that it lets me run 8 jobs on 8 cores, with `bash` I could have them run serially or to fork 1,800 processes, neither of which is good. Adding `\"` in `printf` sure does the job, but `xargs` strips them out. It also strips out `\"\"` or `'\"` or `\"'`, which is my problem.

Comment: Look up Ole Tange's `GNU parallell` for using multiprocessing. It does about the same as xargs , you might have better luck with it. As I said xargs does silly things at times.

Comment: Given Windows and no Perl installed, that's unluckily not an option, did it manually by splitting a file.

Comment: Windows, even with cygwin installed is "weak" in comparison, yes. I do not remember seeing windows mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If a future reader needs a solution that works on CygWin with GNU Parallel:

```
find . -name "*.mp3" | parallel lame {} --abr 52 -q 0 --silent conv/{}
```